# os.chdir(path) not working as expected due to path formatting in Python 2.6.5?

Tags: python

I cannot `os.chdir(path)` in Python 2.6.5 under WindowsXP SP2. It works fine under CygWin and MAC OS X, but for WinXP regardless of `path` format, I always get this error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'chdir'`.

I thought it was the problem with format of `path` but after trying `r"C:\WINDOWS"`, `'C:\WINDOWS'` and combinations of `\\`, `/` or even `"\"C:\Windows\""`, I gave up. With formatting I'm using `os.path.exists(path)` works perfectly fine...

What I am missing here? What should I be aware of when working with paths consisting of white spaces?

Cheers,
Martin

Comment: The error message is a bit strange; it seems to indicate that you have defined a string variable called `os` somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that problem is that in some place you redefine 'os'. Somewhere in your code you do something like this:

```
import os
os = 'some string'
```

Comment: You're correct, Mykola! Thank you very much.  
Anyway, big LOL on me... I'd probably overlook that redefinition and got myself more and more frustrated.